llama-3.1-nemotron-70b-instruct not working with Langchain ChatNVIDIA

UserWarning: Found nvidia/llama-3.1-nemotron-70b-instruct in
available_models, but type is unknown and inference may fail.
warnings.warn(

Python Code to call model
## Core LC Chat Interface
from langchain_nvidia_ai_endpoints import ChatNVIDIA
llm = ChatNVIDIA(model="nvidia/llama-3.1-nemotron-70b-instruct")
result = llm.invoke("Write a ballad about LangChain.")
print(result.content)


did you try the answer?

You can use ChatOpenAI to invoke:
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from openai import OpenAI
import os
ChatOpenAI(
    client=OpenAI(
        base_url = "https://integrate.api.nvidia.com/v1",
        api_key=os.getenv("NVIDIA_API_KEY"),
    ).chat.completions,
).invoke(messages, model="nvidia/llama-3.1-nemotron-70b-instruct")

NVIDIA example

Add the API Key to the environment variable. Environment variable key should be "NVIDIA_API_KEY", and provide your API key as the value. Update the version of langchain-nvidia-ai-endpoints package to 0.3.5. This works for me with your code. Please check if it works for you.
